# Set up Debian networking bridge with DHCP

Tags: debian, dhcp, bridge

After a recent bout of package upgrades (but still within the stretch release) my bridge networking to support libvirt VMs seems to have died - the DHCP server does not send an IP to the host nor does the host have any network connectivity. Previously my `/etc/network/interfaces` file worked great (as has been recommended in the the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections)):

```
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_maxwait 0
```

Alas, when I try to bring it up using `ifup br0` or `systemctl restart networking` I get very unhelpful log messages like `ifup: failed to bring up eth0`.

Most strangely, if I set a static IP on the `br0` interface everything works great, but I'd like to configure my static IPs in the router rather than the host OS.

This is the workaround static IP configuration, closely modeled after the [libvirt networking guide](https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/bridged-network.html).

```
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_maxwait 0
  hwaddress ether e0:3f:49:eb:7f:35
  address 192.168.1.140
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Also, if I remove the bridge entirely and just configure `eth0` to directly use dhcp the host will receive an address from the router.

Any thoughts on what I can do to further troubleshoot or fix the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Huh, that's strange - why should I need a second interface to make the bridge work? In my current workaround configuration and in the demo config on the [libvirt networking guide](https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/bridged-network.html) they both have only one interface configured (and then the VMs attach afterwards).

Comment: Systemd/networkd took over parsing of `/etc/network/interfaces` instead of the (admittedly messy) scripts of ifup/ifdown. So, guess: Your update changed systemd/networkd, and they changed the parsing. So that's where you should start looking (I can't help with details, I switched to Devuan to avoid the systemd instability problems). For example, networkd now insisting that a bridge needs to have two interfaces looks exactly like something they would do (not understanding that you may want to attach more interfaces later).

Comment: libvirt uses bridging to join virtual interfaces (those on VMs) to your network interface. so you'd have only one physical interface, but a few more "virtual" ones. regardless you can have a bridge with a single interface but that has no practical use, unless you plan to join other interfaces to the bridge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your "bridged" interfaces with an empty configuration so they can be brought up ahead of being joined to the bridge interface. I no longer use ifup/down for bridging so I don't have an example at hand. But here's a couple useful samples:

- https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections
- https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Bridging

If you use NetworkManager for handling this, an interface like nmtui makes your life much easier at setting up your bridge.